# Adding a library with more translations than the app has gives errors in string.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

So I added GDPR dialog library in my Android app, which is translated in 10 languages. And my app currently has translations in 7 languages.

Now, the problem is, it shows error for all the strings in my app like below:

[image]

The error says,

```
"load_next" is not translated in "cs"(Czech), etc (names of languages which library has but my app doesn't)
```

My app is in 7 different languages, when I added GDPR library by using `implementation 'com.github.MFlisar:GDPRDialog:LATEST-VERSION'`, this error isn't shown, but as I wanted to make some changes of my own, I downloaded the library and added it as a java module in my app, and then this error started showing up.

App compiles and runs without error (if I've added the translations for all the languages that I've used), but it's a huge inconvenience as I can't just glance at `string.xml` and find out if I missed any translations(as it shows this error for all the text).

So is there any way I can correct this thing without having to:

1. Delete the extra languages in the library
2. Or without suppressing the warning for missing translation, as that's the important thing for me as I have to manage translations for 7 different languages.

Maybe something with which I can suppress this warning only for selected languages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use in the `build.gradle`

```
resConfigs "en", "de", "it", "fr"
```

You can check the [official doc](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor:resConfigs(java.lang.String[])):

> Specifies a list of alternative resources to keep.
>   For example, if you are using a library that includes language resources (such as AppCompat or Google Play Services), then your APK includes all translated language strings for the messages in those libraries whether the rest of your app is translated to the same languages or not. If you'd like to keep only the languages that your app officially supports, you can specify those languages using the resConfigs property, as shown in the sample below. Any resources for languages not specified are removed.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        // Keeps language resources for only the locales specified below.
        resConfigs "en", "fr"
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so hey! I read it, it says "Any resources for languages not specified are removed. That means the same thing right? That it'll remove the languages from the library that I'm not using? The error has definitely gone from the string.xml

Comment: @VedprakashWagh Yes it should (in your final apk it will remove the languages not specified).

Comment: So it'll mean the thing I mentioned in first point right? I kind of want that without having to delete the extra languages. Your solution works but isn't there anything with which I can ignore than warning for those languages without having to remove the extra resources? I'll accept your answer for now though. :)

Comment: So I just thought of something, any way of keeping all the resources of that library by modifying build.gradle of that library?

Comment: @VedprakashWagh I don't find a solution which allows to keep extra languages in the lib and at the same time keeping warning for missing translation only for all the other strings (you should change the strings.xml in the library but I dont' think that it is a good idea)

Comment: So I did science. I added the above resConfigs with the languages that were in the library in build.gradle of that library. Seems to work fine. Now, does that mean it'll not strip the extra languages from that library?

Comment: Yes, `resConfigs` removes extra resources not specified (it can be used not only for strings) in the artifact involved.In the library if you apply it in the `build.gradle` of the library, in the final apk/aab if you apply it in the `build.gradle` of the app.

Comment: So I confirmed it, I built release apk, and analyzed it, seems like it stripped off the extra languages from library even if I added it in individual build.gradle of that library. Thanks though!